# Java Mail: Only one part of the message is retrieved / Parsing error / Badly formatted mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3, multipart

Hello all :) I'm having troubles parsing mails from a pop3 server. In the end I want to get the attachements. The mails are multiparts, but so far I only managed to get a small part of the mail.

Here is the original email, as read by outlook (+one file attached):

```
ID-G1619161

P.S. : This is an automated email.
 Write back to blah@blah.com

Post-scriptum :

This message is confidential. [...]
```

Here is some code:

```
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

    Message message = messages[i];
    System.out.println("message : " + message);
    System.out.println("***");
    IOUtils.copy(message.getInputStream(),System.out);
    System.out.println("***");              
    System.out.println("message.getContentType : " + message.getContentType());
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    System.out.println("multiPart : " + multiPart);
    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();  // line A
}
```

This prints:

```
message : org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.message.POP3Message@79f6f296
***

P.S. : This is an automated email.***
message.getContentType : multipart/mixed; boundary="qMm9M+Fa2AknHoGS"
multiPart : javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@bc92535
```

And throws on line A (`multiPart.getCount`!):

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unexpected response:  Write back to blah@blah.com
```

My take on this is the message is formatted in a weird way that is not recognised by `javax.mail`, because `getCount` is trying to read the rest of the mail.

I can even get the whole message! (Trying to do this at: `IOUtils.copy(message.getInputStream(),System.out);`)

How would you debug this? Also, if you know a way to get the whole mail as a string (attachements included), I'd be very glad you share it. I'm prepared to parse this by hand.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail debugging tips are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

You can get the entire message text using the Message.writeTo method.  Write it to a FileOutputStream or a ByteArrayOutputStream.

You might have better luck using the [JavaMail reference implementation](http://javamail.java.net) instead of the Geronimo(?) version you're using.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the implementation you maintain worked like a charm :) message.getContent gave me a String instead of a Multipart, but the String fit perfectly what I needed.

Comment: @BenoitParis can you please tell me how did you parse the String returned from the method `message.getContent`? I know this is old, but I can't find anything on the web to solve this, I need it to return a Multipart object, or someway I need to parse the String.

Comment: If you really have a multipart message and you're not getting a Multipart object from getContent, please post a new question with the details.